# Use types from .NET 5.0 while remaining compatible with earlier .NET versions like .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, clr, coreclr, .net-5

Suppose you would want to utilize [the new `System.Half`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-half-type/), but you also want your library to be used by .NET Core 3.1 apps (or older). I could simply copy the `System.Half` implementation and lose the intrinsic optimized behavior for older .NET versions, but can I do so in a single assembly?

As far as I know this isn't possible (barring a reflection-style approach, or emit-IL-on-first-use craziness): the above scenario would require separate builds for .NET 5.0 using the build-in `System.Half`) and older .NET versions (using our internal `System.Half`).

But I'm hoping if there's some way to compile/configure a single assembly with some creative type forwarding to utilize the .NET 5.0 version of a given type when it is available, or a shim otherwise.

*(this question is language-agnostic, and not specific to just `System.Half`)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell: No, it is not possible in **a single assembly** - this would need to be done by multi-targeting your library 5.0+ and the lowest version of .NET CCore you want to support and creating a NuGet package of this library.

Applications using the library would then select the best matching assembly, so .NET 5/6/+ Apps would get your .NET 5.0 slice using the runtime's System.Half implementation and .NET Core 3.1 Apps would get the other slice containing your implementation of System.Half that you put behind an `#if`.

Even if you don't want to multi-target your library, a different NuGet package would be needed that provides a slice for .NET (Core) < 5.0 containing an implementation of System.Half. Your library would then depend on this package causing consumers to transitively use this package.

Comment: Thanks, this covers my understanding of the current possibilities. It's unfortunate. I could imagine writing a public version of a type that just throws `NotImplementedException` on invocation and that's somehow marked with a `TypeDelayImplemented` attribute indicating that if the loading path contains a matching version of the type, it's used. Though there'll be many thorns on that road.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it comes down to: is there a nuget package available that offers some part of the API? Note that in the case of something primitive like `Half`, even if there is a nuget package, it might be implemented differently - i.e. no inbuilt JIT/intrinsic support - but it might still work. As an example, consider `Span<T>`, which *works* in down-level frameworks (via nuget), but which works *best* in .NET Core 3.1 or above. As another example, consider `IAsyncDisposable`/`IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, which are available via a nuget package.

Comment: Yes, but the main question here is: can I configure a **single assembly/dll** in such a way that it effortlessly chosses one over the other when referenced? In particular, I'm asking in light of [implementing support for System.Half into `FSharp.Core.dll`](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/issues/500), which should remain a single assembly that remains backwards compatible.

Comment: @Abel that's what the "bait and switch" aspect of package resolution is meant to work in the context of multi-targeted dependencies - meaning: you shouldn't have to do anything, if it has been made *correctly* available in a nuget package

Comment: I mean, can I do something like `#if NET50`, but then at JIT link time, like `TypeForwardedTo`, but then in this case the opposite, `PleaseUseSystemTypeIfAvailableOtherwiseThisOne`. It's the same reason why `FSharp.Core` cannot use `Span` internally yet: it cannot rely on other assemblies than NetStandard ones.

Comment: @Abel the types must be identifiable as the same *to the runtime*; that means that if it *is* packaged in a different library, *that library* would declare it with type-forwarding info; as a consumer, though: you shouldn't have to do anything. This is what already happens for most of the types you're using.

Comment: I think we're talking different things here. If Lib X can only have dependencies on NetStandard, how can I build `X.dll` in such that it uses a `Span` (or System.Half) from `System.Runtime`, and something else if it is not available? Either the runtime chooses my home-grown `Span` always, or it uses the system `Span` always, but the latter is not backwards compatible and I cannot mix and match (or I'm missing something).

Comment: With a 2nd assembly, I see how this may work: either it is present, and it will be chosen, or it is not present, and the type must be found in the runtime libs. But there is no 2nd assembly here (or at least, the F# team holds off on that for now and wants any F# proj to be dependent on one and only one lib).

Comment: @Abel which is why I said it needs to be *identifiable* as the same type; you say "But there is no 2nd assembly here" - again, I point you to my opening comment: "Usually, it comes down to: is there a nuget package available that offers some part of the API?" - which would **provide** the second assembly - which contains a type of the same name/namespace. You're right, there's no easy way to say "this if possible, else that" - but that is not what I suggested/discussed. You multi-target and add the right dependencies per target

Comment: here's a concrete example: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/src/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange.Redis.csproj - see how some package refs are TFM-specific? if I had a netcoreapp3.1 target, I could make even more conditional; for example, netcoreapp3.1 doesn't need `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces`, because `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces` is *literally empty* when targeting netcoreapp3.1 (the types it provides are in the core libs instead)

Comment: The "bait and switch" operation and the multi targeting of a project requires different assemblies. Yes, nuget handles that fine, and it would be OK in almost all cases, but `FSharp.Core.dll` is open source from Microsoft and they specifically want one and only one version of the assembly for any given language version of F# targeting the lowest denominator through NetStandard 2.0 only (in the past this was different, and maybe they'll come back to multiple versions, I dunno).

Comment: @Abel yet it looks like it *does* currently multi-target, with a different package for ns2.0 v netfx: https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Core/ - what you describe is true, but only very recently and not yet in the RTM build: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/commit/8b2422463201b90f90336768d6869e4f606d3d35

Comment: I know, the point is that I asked this question for adding [`System.Half` as a type alias and related casting functions in F#](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/issues/500). But policy is now to drop NetFx 4.5 and have lowest support NetStd 2.0 since [this change](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/commit/8b2422463201b90f90336768d6869e4f606d3d35#diff-645ab24ebf833246dac267d78727cb18) (edit: oh wait, you linked the same ;) ). I've raised an issue to that effect: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/10161